# Terraform, Kubernetes, Mesos etc - how are they connected

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, mesos

Reading a lot on internet but the information is not clear or mixedup so I thought I will ask the question here.

I am trying to understand how Terraform is same or different from container orchestration tools like Kubernetes, Mesos etc.

Can Terraform work independently or Kube and Mesos? How is it connected to docker containers?

Can someone please shed the light?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about Mesos as I would like, but I do know about Kubernetes and Terraform. Despite I'm not an expert the general basics between this tools have a different purpose. While Terraform deals with the generation of the infrastructure in the cloud by using their apis, Kubernetes deals with the administration and orchestration of containers in the undergroown infrastructure by using the api of the container daemon such the docker daemon.

So generally talking the Terraform main point is to make transparent the creation of the cloud infrastructure where you write what you want to have, servers, network, security policies, some PaaS Service and Kubernetes is the orchestrator of containers.

Hope this helps you. Please, in the case of someone saws a mistake. Remark it so we all improves.

Comment: Thank you. So, can terraform be compared to SaltStack or puppet (exclusive to Infrastructure components)?

Kube/Mesos work on the top layer - monitoring of containers deployed on top of the infra?

Comment: I don't know is SaltStack but after a brief browsing I see it is similar to puppet or ansible on its core. Oll of them seem to have modules that allow them to provision infrastructure, aka: create cloud infrastructure, virtualizated infrastructure in VMware ... . With puppet you could latter on even install inside of such infrastructure the components for Kube and even the containers you may play to deploy there. Like Puppet or ansible they do have other modules to connect to such Kubernetes platforms and adminstrate it from its configuration files despite they are the engine who does it.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform - A Tools to Build your Infrastructure an open-source project Hashicorp labs if you are aware with AWS and heard of CloudFormation both work in same manner but Terraform have some better feature you can write your whole Infrastructure as a Code run it in one click and decommissioned it in one click.

For more you must visit the site: https://www.terraform.io

Now Kubernetes (An open source project by Google) and Apache-Mesos( Or DC/OS) An project by Apache foundation both are used for Container orchestration (and I’m purposely avoiding using the word Docker) is not for everyone and does not answer every need.

Mesos was launched first but it was really hard to manage Mesos networking that time. and In 2014 there was the first Release of Kubernetes comes in.

Now, DC/OS (the Distributed Cloud Operating System) is an open-source, distributed operating system based on the Apache Mesos distributed systems kernel.

It's in the race with Kubernetes .

I would suggest you must go through this article to get a better understanding of Kubernetes vs Mesos : https://logz.io/blog/kubernetes-vs-mesos/

And Yes they are not related to Terraform at all.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Prabhat.

Comment: Kubernetes/Mesos doesn't monitor your container cluster For monitoring there are other tools Yes On Kubernetes UI you can have the health and other CPU or Memory utilisation data but now everything to monitor a application cluster.

Comment: Terraform is actually just to write you Infrastructure as a code but using Puppet and Saltstack you can do the more things even you can deploy a Whole Application with Variable and a lot of more things .

Comment: Terraform is similar to AWS CloudFormation  or Azure Resource Manager

Comment: Yes Kubernetes and Mesos are similar but Kubernetes is solution for Cloud native platform either private or public but Mesos was designed for all but hard to manage.

Comment: Thanks Prabhat. Got it. Terraform is purely for infrastructure creation